# What would happens on buffer level when an input stream piping to multi output streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer, fs

I'm reading stream document and looking for buffering behavior description about streams at https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering

The document seems not mentioning about what would happen to inputStream buffer(or buffers?), when piping to multiple outputs as different output have different consuming speeds:

Does the the readableStream keep a dedicated buffer for every output when piping multiple outputs?

Does the outputs keep same speed when consuming or the faster would end earlier?

```js
const input = fs.createReadStream('img.jpg');
const target1 = input.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('target1.jpg'));
const target2 = input.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('target2.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The short answer is - the slower target stream controls the flow rate.

So first of all let's see what happens on read side.

```
const input = fs.createReadStream('img.jpg');
```

When you instantiate the input stream it is created in paused mode and scheduled for reading (no reading is done synchronously, so it will not access the file yet). The stream has `highWaterMark` set to something like `16384` and currently has a buffer of 0 bytes.

```
const target1 = input.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('target1.jpg'));
const target2 = input.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('target2.jpg'));
```

Now when you actually pipe it to the writable streams the flowing mode is set by adding the `on('data')` event handler in the [pipe method implementation - see the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.15.3/lib/_stream_readable.js#L686).

When this is done I assume there's no more program to run, so node starts the actual reading and runs the planned code in the handler above which simply writes any data that comes through.

The flow control happens when any of the targets has more data to write than its `highWaterMark` which cayses the `write` operation to return `false`. The reading is then stopped by [calling pause here in the code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.15.3/lib/_stream_readable.js#L702). Two lines above this you'll see that state.awaitDrain is incremented.

Now the read stream is `paused` again and the writable streams are writing bytes to disk - at some point the buffer level again goes below the `highWaterMark`. At this point a `drain` event is fired which [executes this line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.15.3/lib/_stream_readable.js#L755) and, after **all awaited drains** have been called, resumes the flow. This is done by checking if the decremented `awaitDrain` property has reached zero, which means that all the awaited drain events have been called.

In the above case the faster of the two streams could return a falsy value while writing, but it would definitely drain as the first. If it wasn't for the `awaitDrain` the faster stream would resume the data flow and that would cause a possible buffer overflow in the slower of the two.